# How to re-do Android XML layouts (especially RelativeLayouts) the easy way without redoing all relative relationships?

Tags: android, xml, android-relativelayout

I find myself using RelativeLayout more than any other types of layouts in Android XML files. Given that my apps use primarily simple and basic interfaces, it is quite easy to bang out a new RelativeLayout.

Currently I create a RelativeLayout and I assign each component of the layout properties such as Layout Below, or Layout Left, or Layout Right to anchor that component to the correct area of the user's interface.

While it's easy to define new layouts, it's hell trying to move a single component within a layout. Given that I've used components in my layout to space other components, once a component is moved, the layout around that component falls apart. Moving a component means I have to re-do the relationship for all components below that one. Surely I am doing this wrong? There must be a better way?

TL;DR I use RelativeLayouts and the components I put in the UI to space one-another relatively (of course). If I move a component say to the top, the items below it break as the relative relationship breaks. How can I more easily move components around and experiment with my UI without renaming tens of spacial relationships each time?!

Comment: I dont know what you can do with a Relative Layout, what can't be done by nesting LinearLayouts. Using them instead gives you the 'indipendence' you seem to need. Inside them you are free to switch TextViews and other UI components, without breaking the whole layout. The dependencies are the exact reason I stop using them, as they are to inflexible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is one of the cases where the tooling is preferable over hand-coding the layout XML. Editing the XML using the Graphical Layout tab helps ease lot of this pain of refactoring `RelativeLayout`s. It is not the perfect solution, but it does make things a lot easier.

I should point out that these changes have come about in ADT 14 and newer. If you are using any older ADT, I suggest you upgrade. In case you do not know how to use the Graphical Editor to get the most out of your `RelativeLayout`s, check out [this video](http://developer.android.com/videos/index.html#v=Oq05KqjXTvs).

Having said that, the inflexibility of `RelativeLayout` is the main reason I prefer using nested `LinearLayout`s over the former - in spite of [Google's suggestions to use the former](http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/layout-tricks-efficiency.html) for performance reasons.

As a compromise, I use `RelativeLayout` only for items in a `ListView`, and nested `LinearLayout`s for everything else.

Comment: Good idea, I am using nested LinearLayouts now with RelativeLayouts for listview items (for custom listviews of course).

Answer (score 1):

+1 for the question, since I've been looking for the solution myself. However, I think/feel the only way to do this is by declaring attributes like `android:layout_alignParentBottom` , `android:layout_alignParentLeft` etc. for the items that **can afford** to use those attributes, as they align with the parent, which according to my understanding is the layout itself. Otherwise, I don't see any other way with `Relative Layouts`. As Rafael T says, another way of binding those items to the layout is by using `nested Linear Layouts`. But then again, even that is a bit tedious. Finally it depends on the programmer who chooses the layout. Personally, I'd choose/prefer `Relative Layouts`.